# Initialization of struct elements

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault, boolean

In the following function I allocate space for a struct and assign it to a pointer called `enlace`

```
void insertar_enlace_entre_nodos(nodo_t *nodo1, nodo_t *nodo2, char *de_nombre_if, char *a_nombre_if, unsigned int costo) {
    int ranura1 = obtener_ranura_intf_disp(nodo1);
    int ranura2 = obtener_ranura_intf_disp(nodo2);

    if(ranura1 != -1 && ranura2 != -1) {
        enlace_t *enlace = calloc(1, sizeof(enlace_t));
        inicializar_interface(&enlace->intf1);
        inicializar_interface(&enlace->intf2);
        strncpy(enlace->intf1.nombre_if, de_nombre_if, TAM_NOMBRE_IF);
        enlace->intf1.nombre_if[TAM_NOMBRE_IF - 1] = '\0';
        strncpy(enlace->intf2.nombre_if, a_nombre_if, TAM_NOMBRE_IF);
        enlace->intf2.nombre_if[TAM_NOMBRE_IF - 1] = '\0';

        enlace->intf1.enlace = enlace;
        enlace->intf2.enlace = enlace;
        
        enlace->intf1.nodo_padre = nodo1;
        enlace->intf2.nodo_padre = nodo2;
        nodo1->intf[ranura1] = &(enlace->intf1);
        nodo2->intf[ranura2] = &(enlace->intf2);

        init_prop_intf(enlace->intf1.prop_intf);
        init_prop_intf(enlace->intf2.prop_intf);

        enlace->costo = costo;
    }
}
```

These are structs that I use

```
typedef struct enlace_ enlace_t;

struct enlace_ {
    interface_t intf1;
    interface_t intf2;
    unsigned int costo;
};

typedef struct interface_ {
    char nombre_if[TAM_NOMBRE_IF];
    struct nodo_ *nodo_padre;
    struct enlace_ *enlace;
    prop_intf_t *prop_intf;
} interface_t;

typedef struct prop_intf_ {
    bool tiene_dir_ip;
    dir_ip_t dir_ip;
    dir_mac_t dir_mac;
    char mascara;
} prop_intf_t;
```

Even tough I didn't initialize any element of `intf1`, I can modify `nombre_if` and I don't get any error

```
strncpy(enlace->intf1.nombre_if, de_nombre_if, TAM_NOMBRE_IF);
```

But when I get to this other function the debugger shows me a segmentation fault error and the program ends. It happens at the first instruction.

```
static inline void init_prop_intf(prop_intf_t *prop_intf) {
    prop_intf->tiene_dir_ip = false;
    prop_intf->mascara = 0;
    memset(prop_intf->dir_ip.dir_ip, 0, 16);
    memset(prop_intf->dir_mac.dir_mac, 0, 6);
}
```

The error message is **Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000555555555277 in init_prop_intf (prop_intf=0x0) at ../src/Net.h:40
40              prop_intf->tiene_dir_ip = false;
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
The program no longer exists.**

So I want to know why in the first case nothing goes wrong and in the second one it does and when is it mandatory to initialize the elements of a struct.

Comment: "*I didn't initialize any element of intf1, I can modify nombre_if*" The `nombre_if` field is an array and *writing* to an unintialised array is perfectly fine (though in this case the array actually is initialised by the `calloc`). So it's not clear why you think that line of code is wrong.

Comment: The second case where you do get segv is different to the first case. `prop_intf` is an unintialised pointer and dereferencing an uninialised pointer is indeed Undefned Behaviour. So in summary, `nombre_if` is a valid pointer whereas `prop_intf` is not.

Comment: @kaylum Okay, I didn't think of that. Thank you.